# Need to insert header information in wsdl

Tags: wsdl

I would like to insert soap header information in wsdl, can someone suggest me or provide me code snippet how do I do. I have wsdl but that does not have soap header. So I want to write a program to insert header information and then copy all content of wsdl and then generate new wsdl. So I need to transform all my wsdl into new with soap header. Please help me .

My old wsdl is like this:

```
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
```

I want like this:

```
<wsdl:input>
<soap:header message="tns:SOAPHeader" part="info" use="literal"/>
<soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried

Comment: Thanks Nishant123 for reading my post